# Run console application in background

Tags: python

I am working on a script in python where first I set ettercap to ARP poisoning and then start urlsnarf to log the URLs. I want to have ettercap to start first and then, while poisoning, start urlsnarf. The problem is that these jobs must run at the same time and then `urlsnarf` show the output. So I thought it would be nice If I could run ettercap in background without waiting to exit and then run urlsnarf. I tried command nohup but at the time that urlsnarf had to show the url the script just ended. I run:

```
subprocess.call(["ettercap",
                 "-M ARP /192.168.1.254/ /192.168.1.66/ -p -T -q -i wlan0"])
```

But I get:

> ettercap NG-0.7.4.2 copyright 2001-2005 ALoR & NaGA
>
> MITM method ' ARP /192.168.1.254/ /192.168.1.66/ -p -T -q -i wlan0' not supported...

Which means that somehow the arguments were not passed correctly

Answer (score 1):

You could use the subprocess module in the Python standard library to spawn ettercap as a separate process that will run simultaneously with the parent. Using the Popen class from subprocess you'll be able to spawn your ettercap process run your other processing and then kill the ettercap process when you are done. More info here: [Python Subprocess Package](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

```
import shlex, subprocess

args = shlex.split("ettercap -M ARP /192.168.1.254/ /192.168.1.66/ -p -T -q -i wlan0")
ettercap = subprocess.Popen(args)

# program continues without waiting for ettercap process to finish.
```

Comment: You need to use the Popen class in subprocess. The call function won't what you want since it will wait for the process to finish. For the arguments each one needs to be a separate element in the list. I.e ["ettercap", "-M", "APR", ...]

Comment: This: subprocess.call(["ettercap", "-M", "ARP", "/192.168.1.254/", "/192.168.1.1/", "-p", "-T", "-q", "-i", "wlan0"])                    works exactly as if os.system("ettercap -M arp /192.168.1.254/ /192.168.1.66/ -p -T -q -i wlan0")

Comment: Correct. Both subprocess.call() and os.system() call an external process and wait for it to finish. Since you don't want to wait for your process to finish, you need to use subprocess.Popen() in order to run your subprocess concurrently with your main program:

    `import shlex, subprocess  

    args = shlex.split("ettercap -M ARP /192.168.1.254/ /192.168.1.66/ -p -T -q -i wlan0")  

    ettercap = subprocess.Popen(args)  

    # program continues without waiting for ettercap process to finish.  
`

Comment: Updated main answer with example code. It didn't format well in the previous comment.